# what structure should has the JSON returned on backend, to pass values for each datatable's column footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

For now I managed to pass columns definition, names, visiblity, and data to be displayed.

There is a lot info in documentation how to calculate it on client site, but I would like do it on backend.

Here is a demo of JSON, which I return on backend: https://gist.github.com/andilab/717b73cbfd876ddfeed1

I GET the definitions of columns and data using following js (coffescript) code:

```
    $.ajax
        dataType: "json"
        type: "GET"
        url: "/the/url/"
        success: (data) ->
            $("#example").DataTable
                data: data.aaData
                columns: data.aaColumnsDefs
```

I am using version `1.10.2` of `datatables`

The **QUESTION** is what should be correct form of JSON returned on backend, so that I am able to pass the values for each column footer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following answer on datatable forum http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/7326/footer-with-javascript-array-as-source-of-data **it seems being not possible** to do it in the same - automatic - way like for columns. 
But you can partially automate it by defining own actions on DOM, and passing in JSON also information about footers, using `footerCallback: ()`.

```
$.ajax
    dataType: "json"
    type: "GET"
    url: "/the/url/"
    success: (data) ->
        generate_empty_cells = Array(data.footers.length+1).join "<th style='text-align:right'></th>"
        $("#example tfoot tr").append(generate_empty_cells)
        $("#example").DataTable
            data: data.aaData
            columns: data.aaColumnsDefs
            footerCallback: () ->
                api = @api()
                   for th, index in footers
                        $(api.column(index).footer()).html(th)
```

HTML:

```
<table id="example">
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

In HTML we define empty row, and in JS generate appropriate number of cells `generate_empty_cells = Array(data.footers.length+1).join "<th style='text-align:right'>` based on length of passed array. If you don't want for some column value in footer just put `null` in appropriate place in array.

Example of JSON was updated in gist linked in question.
Notice that names like `aaData`, `aaColumnDefs` or `footers` can be anything you like.

Answer (score 0):

You should use brackets and comas.
Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    url: "/the/url/",
    data: {field_name:value,...}, // here you passing data to server side
    success: function(data){
        // here write code that treats the data received
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: You have misunderstood me. I provided the question exact now. It is not matter of how to perform ajax call. I am thankfully fine with it ;-) The issue is what parameter should be returned in JSON on backend, so that DATATABLE knows what to display in each column footer.